# `TextArea.setOnScroll` doesn't be invoked when I scroll mouse wheel?

Tags: scroll, javafx, mouseevent

I have a TextArea, and have been set a handler for the scroll event:

```
myTextarea.setOnScroll((event) -> {
     System.out.println("setOnScroll: " + event);
});
```

But I found when the text in the textarea are very long, and if I put my mouse on it and scroll the mouse wheel, it doesn't print the event!

Only if the text reaches to the end, it starts to show the event.

I also tried `setOnScrollStarted`, and `setOnScrollFinished`, the same situation happens.

How to capture each scroll event in JavaFX?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution:

```
myTextarea.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, (x) -> {
    System.out.println("scrolled");
});
```

Seems a little strange to use the method `addEventFilter`, but it works.